# New install indicator while install updating on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, updates, package-management, packages

In the update manager of ubuntu I see several libraries marked with New Install.
I don't know what is the benefit I can get from that New Install?
What if I just want a normal upgrade, not a New Install?

*(I have 3 Linux Kernel versions right now (that I can see and select from Grub menu), and I think I don't need all of them since I always use the latest Kernel).*

Answer (score 0):

Generally you will get libraries lined up to be installed when you install an application that needs them. Also if a new version of a program needs libraries that were previously unneeded it will cause them to be automatically installed.

If you are curious about why a library is being installed you can look at the list of programs that require that library. Also you can mark a library to be removed, and will be prompted with the list of applications that would also need to be uninstalled because they rely on that library. Regarding the older kernel versions, it is safe to mark all unused kernels for removal (as long as the one you don't remove actually boots).